# Laravel - How to pass variable to constructor to model and then use eloquent? dynamic set database connection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, constructor, model

I have an issue that I am struggling to resolve where I am trying to dynamically set the database connection when constructing the instance of the model. However I am struggling to use eloquent once I initialise the model.

In my model, I have the following constructor:

```
public function __construct(School $school, array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    if ($school instanceof School) {

        $host = $school->database;

        Config::set('database.connections.school', [
            'driver'   => 'mysql',
            'host'     => $host->host,
            'port'     => $host->port,
            'database' => $host->database_name,
            'username' => $host->database_username,
            'password' => $host->database_password,
        ]);

        $this->setConnection('school');

    }

}
```

Then in my controller I am trying to query the data like:

```
$student = new Student($this->selected_school);
$this->student = $student::query()->where('student_reference_code', $this->student_reference_code)->first();
```

However I am recieving the following error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Models\Student::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/user/Sites/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 1321 and at least 1 expected

I'm not sure whether this is the best way to set the database connection as each school will have seperate databases.

Any help on how I am able to use eloquent to query the model using the correct database connection by passing through the school would be much appreciated.

--

I have also tried to create a method within the model like:

```
public function getStudentByStudentReferenceCode($reference_code)
{
    return $this->where('student_reference_code', $this->student_reference_code)->first();
}


$this->student = $student->getStudentByStudentReferenceCode($this->student_reference_code);
```

However then I recieve the following:

> App\Models\Student::__construct(): Argument #1 ($school) must be of type App\Models\School, array given, called in /Users/user/Sites/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 496

When dumping out what I am passing into new Student() constructor, and it is an instance of the school model?

Comment: the Model constructor has to start with the optional `$attributes` array as the framework code will be creating new model instances expecting that signature

Comment: @lagbox - just updated model to public function __construct(array $attributes = [], School $school) and then calling like new Student([],$school) but still same error (Too few arguments to function App\Models\Student::__construct(), 0 passed)

Comment: they would all have to be optional parameters since the original signature is a single optional parameter

Comment: I'm sorry you lost me there :/ How would I set an optional parameter to the constructor?

Comment: Do NOT overwrite Eloquent model constructors. It will give you constant headaches.  When you call `$student::query()` it is creating a new instance of itself... without the school passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwriting the Eloquent model constructor is going to give you lots of trouble, don't do that. Laravel expects that it should be able to `new static` at anytime without issue, which it can't do if you added a required parameter to the constructor.

Instead, I recommend doing something like this in your model:

```
public static function connect(School $school)
{
    $host = $school->database;

    
    \Config::set('database.connections.school', [
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => $host->host,
        'port'     => $host->port,
        'database' => $host->database_name,
        'username' => $host->database_username,
        'password' => $host->database_password,
    ]);
    
    \DB::purge('school');

    return (new static)->setConnection('school');
}
```

Now use your own method when creating a new instance of your model, like this:

```
$student = Student::connect($this->selected_school)
    ->where('student_reference_code', $this->student_reference_code)
    ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works, the query works, however I am using it within a livewire component and once I set the connection, any actions to any of the wire:click cause SQL error - lluminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Comment: it appears livewire attempts to requery itself, without using the ::connect method, and therefore trys to connect to the incorrect database :/ Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: @heady12 Would have been useful to know that up front! You now need to look at `PersistentMiddleware` for livewire, and see how you can restore a DB connection, ideally based on route parameters (that's how I do it anyway). That is a completely separate question though. If this answer solves the question you posed, please mark it accepted and open a new question for how to handle livewire specifically.

Comment: Thanks @jszobody, will take a look over the livewire middleware :) Your solution works well, however I have noticed some issues where eloquent doesn't take into account the connect method as the method opens a new static instance? example:
SchoolClass::connect('school_' . $host->id)->all() -> attempts to connect to wrong DB.

Comment: @heady12 Try putting `protected $connection = "school";` in your model at the top. Once you write out the `school` DB config, you want your model to just use that even if you haven't explicitly set it in each instance.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it throws an error because I dont have the connection set in config/database.php - I added a connection there but then it connects to the default connection set from database.php and not the connection from the config::set

Comment: Instead of using ->all() that calls a new instance, I am instead using ->get([*]) to work around the issues with eloquent for now. 
Is there no way to use the connect method within the constructor so that it's already set?

Comment: You don't want to do it in the constructor, at all. If it throws an error because you don't have a connection set... set it! I mean, right? I don't understand the issue here. Have a stubbed `school` connection in your config file, and update it in your `connect()` method just like I showed you.